# linked server OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql, openquery

Hello I have 2 different SQL Server databases.

They are connected to each other via a linked server.   The linked server is working fine.

When i try:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    OPENQUERY
        ([192.168.1.170], 
        'SELECT MalCRM.dbo.ContractedNumber(1)')
```

I get the below error. How I can fix it?

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "192.168.1.170" returned message "Deferred prepare could not be completed.".
>   Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 1
>   The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'ContractedNumber', database 'MalCrm', schema 'dbo'.

Comment: Try running the query `SELECT MalCRM.dbo.ContractedNumber(1)` directly on the linked server, using the same login.  You will almost certainly find that account does not have the full set of required permissions.

Comment: Sorry i am not sure i understood as well. Can you explain more detaily please ? select statement works as well on the target server. but when i try to run by db link i can not.

Comment: I suspect you cannot run the query directly on [192.168.1.170].  Although the link is in place, you do not have the necessary permissions on that server.  Connect to [192.168.1.170] via ssms.  Run the query (`SELECT MalCRM.dbo.ContractedNumber(1)`).  If you get the same error message then ask dba to amend your permissions.

Comment: 160 DwhCRM 170 MalCRM. select working on 160 but does not on 170. i have sys permission also if u can direct i can give this to myself.

Comment: What account does the link use to connect to 170?  That account does not have execute permission on the function `ContractedNumber`.

Comment: account has an execute permission but still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merhaba Berhan,

I tried following sql query which works perfect

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([myInstance], 'SELECT AdventureWorks.dbo.test(3)')
```

Did you check the credentials on the database function is valid?
It seems to be a permission issue.
Please check the [SQL Server linked server](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2012/how-to-add-sql-server-linked-server.aspx) security context and check if it has execute permission on the database object.
On the referred tutorial, on security context you can map the source database user to an other user on the linked server.
That might be the issue

Comment: Merhaba Alper, i can retrieve result from select but only when i go to linkedserver properties-security and choose impersonate. If its not impersonate i am getting error as i wrote. Any solution ?

Comment: So why don't you change the link server configuration as "impersonate" selected. This will map the SQL logins on both servers

Comment: i choosed this for any user after they begun to can not connect to database=) i dont know what to do now ?

Comment: If you mapped the login user in source database to an other user in destination, the queries will work with second login's credentials. If you did not assign it to a different user, than your existing login should exist in the target instance. You can run a sql profiler and trace the queries to see error in detail. You might be required to alter the execute permissions on the sp or user-defined function you are trying